# How to display correct wording in Kibana4 (beta3)

Tags: kibana

I can see a good aggregation chart under "Discover" tab http://goo.gl/zzzQ6u, but when I click the "Visualize" and will see a wrong wording bar chart as http://goo.gl/38JhVc.

The X-Axis is supposed to be like "SM-G7102", "HTC One_M8"...

Does anyone know how to display correct wording ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your field has been "analyzed" by ElasticSearch (that's its job).  You want the non-analyzed version of the string.  Logstash makes you one for each field, available as field.raw.

Change your visualization to use that field.

Comment: Thanks, I am a newbie in ES. I finally change the mapping setting and reindex my data and it's work.